# Ionic - Authorization field on request header - How does this work?

Tags: node.js, angular, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

I just downloaded an `Ionic` project from internet. This project is divided into 2 sub-projects: { `Server (NodeJS)` / `Client (Ionic)` }

This project makes use of an authentication process based on `JWT` (tokens) not sessions.

On the `Client (Ionic)` sub-project I have the following fragment of code:

```
...
createTodo(todo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', this.authService.token);
        this.http
            .post(
                'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/todos',
                JSON.stringify(todo),
                { headers: headers }
            )
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    resolve(res);
                },
                err => {
                    reject(err);
                }
            );
    });
}
...
```

My question is, how the `Authorization` field on the request headers works?

Why the token is not sent as a parameter like the `todo` object?

I checked on the `server` sub-project and there is no reference to that `Authorization` field there, at least not explicitly.

Could you clear this for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not node specific.

Well, authorization is often executed at the beginning of the request pipeline. This means; before all (a-lot of) other things; authorization needs to be handled first.

This typically is a system-wide defined piece of logic; therefor it's not a typical thing for a specific end-point to handle; therefor; a parameter is unsuited and that's where the http-headers comes in.

I don't know the framework; but my guess is there exists some authorization filter somewhere, which handles your token.

Headers a commonly for system-wide logic. Such as, but not limited to:

- authorization
- authentication
- request type
- content type
- cors
- accepted encoding
- accepted compression
- .. .ah wel, just check wikipedia

For a list of common headers see: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Please note that authorization can be handled by/at a third party server like google/facebook etc.